# $D=\left\{ \left( x,y,z\right) :z\neq 0\right\}$,and find a potential if it is.

Tags: calculus

Describe whether the vector field $F=\left( xy-\sin z\right) i+\left( \dfrac {1}{2}x^{2}-\dfrac {e^{y}}{z}\right) j+\left( \dfrac {e^{y}}{z^{2}}-x\cos z\right) k$ is conservative in $D=\left\{ \left( x,y,z\right) :z\neq 0\right\}$,and find a potential if it is.

Comment: This is not a do-my-homework-for-me website. What have you tried? You should demonstrate some effort and explain where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The potential function is $\phi(x,y,z)={x^2y\over 2}-{e^y\over z}-x\sin z$